could not find driver SQL
I have the following problem, when trying to connect to a SqlServer server, it shows that I don't have the driver.
"could not find driver (SQL: select [Name], [ContractID] from [Contract] where [statusID] = 1 order by [Name] asc)
Previous exceptions
could not find driver (0)
could not find driver (0)"
I'm using ubuntu 20.04.2 lts
Php 7.4.33 (I can't change the php since the projects were made in this version, if I change it I won't have access)
[ENcabezadp phpinfo (https://i.sstatic.net/prpVXHfg.png)

Please provide a [mcve], along with the full output it produces. Use text for that, not images which can't be (hint!!) searched. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
